# Search results API Deezer

Tags: api, deezer

I manipulate Deezer API and i'm very disappointed about the results for search ! For example :

[Rihanna Stay](http://api.deezer.com/search?q=rihanna%20stay)

[The Monster Eminem](http://api.deezer.com/search?q=the%20monster%20eminem)

[Michael Jackson Bad](http://api.deezer.com/search?q=michael%20jackson%20bad)

So popular title and found anything, first track found is ugly... Deezer Api not found any good true track. Anybody have another solution ? Or Deezer can reply ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: From what I gather, the search query look for a match in the song title or the artist name. In your case you mix both which explain why you don't have the result you want. What you could do instead is make a query on the song's title for instance, then filter the result to only song's whise artist name matches the one you want.

Comment: If you want to get the most popular tracks, you just have to add a parameter "order=RATING_DESC" like mentioned in the documentation: http://developers.deezer.com/api/search#infos

Comment: Thanks, i used "RANKING" and yes, "RATING_DESC" is exactly what i want !